# How to make this query efficient and faster when the data exist up to millions data

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, rank

**Is there a solution to display rank data more quickly and efficiently**
**The query that I use feels slow because the data is already very much**

**I have table and data:**

**Table 1:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `location_id` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `location_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `table1` (`location_id`,`location_name`) VALUES 
('001','Asia'),('002','Africa');

+-------------+---------------+
| location_id | location_name | 
+-------------+---------------+
| 001         | Asia          |
| 002         | Africa        |
+-------------+---------------+
```

**Table 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `device_id` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `device_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_id` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`device_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `table2` (`device_id`,`device_name`, `location_id`) VALUES 
('D001','Water Level','001'),('D002','Air Direction','001'),('D003','Rain Fall','001');

+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| device_id | device_name   | location_id |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| D001      | Water Level   | 001         | 
| D002      | Air Direction | 001         | 
| D003      | Rain Fall     | 001         |
+-----------+---------------+-------------+
```

**Table 3:**

```
CREATE TABLE `table3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `send_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `table3` (`device_id`,`send_date`, `value`) VALUES 
('D001','2021-07-11 07:00',30.10),
('D001','2021-07-11 07:30',29.21),
('D001','2021-07-11 08:00',31.07),
('D002','2021-07-11 07:00',28.18),
('D002','2021-07-11 07:30',30.10),
('D002','2021-07-11 08:00',31.07),
('D003','2021-07-11 07:00',29.21),
('D003','2021-07-11 07:30',31.07),
('D003','2021-07-11 08:00',30.10),
('D001','2021-07-12 07:00',30.10),
('D001','2021-07-12 07:30',29.21),
('D001','2021-07-12 08:00',31.07),
('D002','2021-07-12 07:00',28.18),
('D002','2021-07-12 07:30',30.10),
('D002','2021-07-12 08:00',31.07),
('D003','2021-07-12 07:00',29.21),
('D003','2021-07-12 07:30',31.07),
('D003','2021-07-12 08:00',30.10);

+----------------+---------------------+-------+
| id | device_id | send_date           | value |
+--------------- +---------------------+-------+
| 1  | D001      | 2021-07-11 07:00:00 | 30.1  |
| 2  | D001      | 2021-07-11 07:30:00 | 29.21 |
| 3  | D001      | 2021-07-11 08:00:00 | 31.07 |
| 4  | D002      | 2021-07-11 07:00:00 | 28.18 |
| 5  | D002      | 2021-07-11 07:30:00 | 30.1  |
| 6  | D002      | 2021-07-11 08:00:00 | 31.07 |
| 7  | D003      | 2021-07-11 07:00:00 | 29.21 |
| 8  | D003      | 2021-07-11 07:30:00 | 31.07 |
| 9  | D003      | 2021-07-11 08:00:00 | 30.1  |
| 10 | D001      | 2021-07-12 07:00:00 | 30.1  |
| 11 | D001      | 2021-07-12 07:30:00 | 29.21 |
| 12 | D001      | 2021-07-12 08:00:00 | 31.07 |
| 13 | D002      | 2021-07-12 07:00:00 | 28.18 |
| 14 | D002      | 2021-07-12 07:30:00 | 30.1  |
| 15 | D002      | 2021-07-12 08:00:00 | 31.07 |
| 16 | D003      | 2021-07-12 07:00:00 | 29.21 |
| 17 | D003      | 2021-07-12 07:30:00 | 31.07 |
| 18 | D003      | 2021-07-12 08:00:00 | 30.1  |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+
```

**I use this query to display 1 data per group, but when there are millions of data, the query will feel very slow**

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
    a.`location_name`,c.`device_id`,b.`device_name`,c.`send_date`,c.`value`,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.`device_id` ORDER BY c.send_date DESC) AS ranking
    FROM
    table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.`location_id`=a.`location_id`
    INNER JOIN table3 c ON c.`device_id`=b.`device_id`  
    ) AS ta
WHERE ta.ranking = 1
ORDER BY ta.device_id ASC
```

**Output:**

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------------+-------+---------+
| location_name | device_name   | send_date           | value | ranking |
+---------------+---------------+---------------------+-------+---------+
| Asia          | Water Level   | 2021-07-12 09:00:00 | 28.18 |     1   |
| Asia          | Air Direction | 2021-07-12 09:00:00 | 28    |     1   |
| Asia          | Rain Fall     | 2021-07-12 09:00:00 | 28    |     1   |
+---------------+---------------+---------------------+-------+---------+
```

**Help me, please.
Because if I use the query when the data reaches millions the process will very slow**
**Thanks for your answer**

Comment: Please edit your question to add (as text, not an image) output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * ...rest of your query`

Comment: What are you doing with the millions of rows of data being produced? Writing to a file? Your DDL indicates you don't have any indexes - that's the first thing to do. What does the query plan look like?

Comment: I want to get the last value in the group, but if I use the RANK() method then when the data is already millions, the query will be slow because it has to first calculate the number of data per group

Comment: You should have an index on `table3(device_id, send_date)`. Then, numbering all rows in order to find the latest entries is a lot of work. Finding the maximum date is much easier (especially with that index). Hence it may be better to select `MAX(c.send_date) OVER (PARTITION BY c.device_id) AS max_date` and replace `WHERE ta.ranking = 1` by `ta.send_date = ta.max_date`. Or access table3 twice and use a subquery for the comparision. Correlated as shown by Gordon or non-correlated with `WHERE (c.device_id, c.send_date) IN (SELECT device_id, MAX(send_date) FROM table3 GROUP BY device_id)`.

Comment: It looks like you're using a relation db to store telemetry data.  Telemetry data is time-series data, so why don't you use a timeseries db (like influxdb, timescaledb, Timeseries Insights .... )

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find a correlated subquery faster, with the right indexes:

```
SELECT a.`location_name`, c.`device_id`, b.`device_name`, c.`send_date`, c.`value`
FROM table1 a JOIN
     table2 b
     ON b.`location_id` = a.`location_id` JOIN
     table3 c
     ON c.`device_id` = b.`device_id`
WHERE c.send_date = (SELECT MAX(c2.send_date)
                     FROM table3 c2
                     WHERE c2.device_id = c.device_id
                    );
```

The index you want is on `table3(device_id, send_date)`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table3_device_id_send_date ON table3(device_id, send_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

- See the tag I added.
- Do the `JOINs` *after* getting the top-ranked rows.  That is, work with "ranking" of `c` by itself, then `JOIN` to `b` and `a`.
- Add this index:

  ```
    c:  INDEX(device_id, send_date, value)
  ```